# Why would the IPMIEVD service start and then stop on a Sun x4100 system running Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ipmi

I've a system that was recently upgraded (within the last month) from Server 2003 to Server 2008.  It's one of several identically configured systems, and the siblings are all happily in production after the OS upgrade.

However, this specific system refuses to run the IPMIEVD service - when started, it shows the following dialog message:

"The ipmievd service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

I've been looking into my event logs to discover any potential clues for this behavior, but the service stopping due to "nothing to do" isn't considered an error, apparently, as I've nothing showing up in the logs.  I've also ensured that I have the Microsoft IPMI device driver loaded and showing no issues.  A stare-and-compare of this system and its immediate sibling isn't really helping either - both boxes are running a bare-bones install of Server 2008, running the same Mediaroom roles.  The server is working - but without IPMI, I've no way of trapping hardware events to my logs, and thus to SCOM.

Anyone have any insight into this problem?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the service have any dependicies listed? And are they all running?

Comment: no dependencies.  BUT... see the answer posted.  It was sitting right in the SUN documentation too... yet another case of RTFM (carefully). http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19411-01/820-2771-16/820-2771-16.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, while IPMIEVD is version-agnostic when it comes to Server 2003 and Server 2008, the IPMI driver one binds it to is not.  Server 2003 does not come with an IPMI driver "out of the box", so one has to install the Sun ISM driver to provide an IPMI interface to the hardware.  Server 2008, by contrast, has a Microsoft generic IPMI driver built into the system.

For 2003, one installs the service thus:

`C:\Program Files\ipmievd\ipmievd.exe -I ism sel`

For 2008, it is slightly different:

`C:\Program Files\Ipmievd\ipmievd.exe -I ms sel`

These two methods can be exposed by opening up the service properties and examining the command line.

Once I discovered that the 2008 installation had been installed as if it were a 2003 installation, I just had to uninstall the service:

`C:\Program Files\Ipmievd\ipmievd.exe -u`

and then re-install it with the correct parameters for Server 2008.

Thanks all! Hope this proves useful for anyone running into IPMIevd issues on a Windows server.